# R multinomial logistic regression interpretation

Tags: r, regression, multinomial-distribution, interpretation

I have run a `multinomial logistic regression` test for the interaction between species of deer, days a camera trap was in the field and type of reaction.

The model with the best AIC value was:

```
Coefficients:
   (Intercept) speciesmuntjac   speciesroe speciessika        days
r   -0.7471023      0.6263753 -0.005967869 -0.74253017 -0.05189515
sr   0.6909319      0.5552278 -0.355611180 -0.01622306 -0.03178001

Residual Deviance: 971.6464 
AIC: 991.6464
```

But I also got the following

```
    (Intercept) speciesmuntjac speciesroe speciessika       days
r  0.0071741793     0.17599897  0.9865350   0.2095687 0.08669276
sr 0.0001402185     0.08536257  0.1331651   0.9574258 0.08829020
```

I'm just wondering if anyone knows why this is considered the best model when neither days nor deer react (r) or strongly react (sr) higher than chance?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting the results of a statistical model. It is not a questions about programming since the code seems to be running fine. As already suggested, this is likely a better fit for [stats.se]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated? Can you identify which `R` commands give the responses you see here?